# Promise { <pending> } - Trying to await for .map

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using `.map` to map out a new object and to add the old price to the map.

I am using Async/Await with my datamaps, here is what my code looks like:

```
let datasets = await changes.map(async (data) => {
  let products = {};
  let last = await models.prices.findOne({
    where: {
        productId: data.productId,
        sourceId: data.sourceId
    },
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    limit: 1,
    offset: 1
  });

  products.name   = data.product.name;
  products.price  = data.price;
  products.sku    = data.product.sku;
  products.source = data.source.name;
  products.link   = data.link;
  products.diff   = last.price;


  return products;
});
```

`changes` are all of the prices changes found in the last 24 hours.

`last` contains the previous time a price change was found of the particular product.

The `return products` isn't waiting, so I get a spam of `Promise { <pending> }` messages. If I use a `console.log(last)` it's working inside, but I cannot figure out the correct way to slow down the return.

`products.diff = last.price` is the one piece that needs to fill for this to be valid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`await` awaits on Promises but `Array.prototype.map` returns a new array of Promises. You need to wrap it with `Promise.all`

```
let datasets = await Promise.all(changes.map(async (data) => {
  let products = {};
  let last = await models.prices.findOne({
    where: {
        productId: data.productId,
        sourceId: data.sourceId
    },
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    limit: 1,
    offset: 1
  });

  products.name   = data.product.name;
  products.price  = data.price;
  products.sku    = data.product.sku;
  products.source = data.source.name;
  products.link   = data.link;
  products.diff   = last.price;


  return products;
}));
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks, works perfectly. I have a wait time, then I put yours as the answered question.

Comment: @MilesCollier No problem :)

Comment: i could have saved my two days if i had found this answer earlier. Thanks Yury.