# Async-await 'Promise {<pending>} with Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I know there are many questions discuss about the same error and I saw most of them and they didn't fix my problem.
I wrote this code:

```
const userOrganizationGroups = (organizationGroupsList) => {
 if (Array.isArray(organizationGroupsList) && organizationGroupsList.length) {
    const result = organizationGroupsList.map(async (element) => {
      const { organizationId, groupId } = element;
      const { Organizations, Groups } = models;


      const organization = await Organizations.findOne(
        { _id: organizationId },
        { name: 1, _id: 0 },
      );
      const group = await Groups.findOne({ _id: groupId });
      return Object.assign({}, {
        organizationName: organization.name,
        group: group.name,
      });
    });
    return result;
  }

};
```

when I debug the code:

```
console.log('userOrganizationGroups : ',userOrganizationGroups(list))
```

I got such a  result:

```
userOrganizationGroups: Promise { <pending> }
```

I found a similair question: [Promise {  } - Trying to await for .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072479/promise-pending-trying-to-await-for-map) and I used the solution mentioned in the question:

```
const userOrganizationGroups = async (organizationGroupsList) => {


 if (Array.isArray(organizationGroupsList) && organizationGroupsList.length) {
    const result = await Promise.all(organizationGroupsList.map(async (element) => {
      const { organizationId, groupId } = element;
      const { Organizations, Groups } = models;


      const organization = await Organizations.findOne(
        { _id: organizationId },
        { name: 1, _id: 0 },
      );
      const group = await Groups.findOne({ _id: groupId });
      return Object.assign({}, {
        organizationName: organization.name,
        group: group.name,
      });
    }));
    return result;
  }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

`console.log('userOrganizationGroups : ',userOrganizationGroups(list))`

use

`userOrganizationGroups(list).then( groups => console.log('userOrganizationGroups : ', groups)`

or

`(async () => {
    const groups = await userOrganizationGroups(list);
    console.log('userOrganizationGroups : ', groups);
})();`

Comment: Thanks to this article https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-how-to-run-an-asynchronous-function-in-array-map and your comment I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` was called first because you didn't wait using `await` or `then`.

So You should write below instead of
 `console.log('userOrganizationGroups : ',userOrganizationGroups(list))`

```
;(async () => {
    const resultGroups = await userOrganizationGroups(list)
    resultGroups.forEach(group => {
      console.log(`group: ${JSON.stringfy(group, null, '  ')}`)
    })
})()
```